# Bigquery appends exactly half part of a table to another

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to append the a local `jsonlines` file `jl` to table `t2`. However, bigquery appended exactly  half of the number of rows of `jl` to `t2`. I mean there are 935.094 rows at `jl` but it only transferred 467.547 of them. I wonder if there are such limitations when appending local file to a table.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def append_local_file_to_table(self,file_path,dataset_id,existing_table):
    table_ref=self.client.dataset(dataset_id).table(existing_table)

    load_job_config=bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    load_job_config.write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    load_job_config.source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

    with open(file_path,'rb') as jl:
        load_job=self.client.load_table_from_file(jl,table_ref,job_config=load_job_config)
    load_job.result()
```

Comment: I don't feel a system limitation is hit. If I were debugging it, I would start with 10 rows of data to see if still only 5 of them got injected. If it works, I would gradually increase the amount of data to see when it starts to have problem.

Comment: Agree with @YunZhang. Try reproducing with files with less rows, and different files. It is quite odd that exactly half of your rows were appended. There is no limitation in that sense, and if it were it would be way bigger. Did you get any error message? Seeing that the appended rows are exactly half of the total, one thing that came to my mind is this: is it possible that your local file contains all rows duplicated by any chance?